# I am trying to use a bash script to set my paths in linux but it is not working

Tags: linux, bash, path

I have this bash script but it wont set the paths and I am not sure why. I can set the paths manually by typing each command.

```
#!/bin/bash
   
parent_path=$( cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" ; pwd -P )
   
export PATH=$PATH:$parent_path/arm-2013.11/bin;
export ARMGCC_INSTALL_PATH=$parent_path/arm-2013.11;
export ARMGCC_VERSION=4.8.1;
```

Comment: Think of it like DNA: your children inherit some of yours when they are born - you don't inherit your descendants' after they die. This is why the `source` ("dot") command exists - to execute commands in the parent process directly.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `source`/`.` built-in to run this script.

Running vs Sourcing the script:
Running the script opens a new shell. All changes to the environment will be lost after the program executes.
Sourcing the script runs the script in the current shell. Think of `.bashrc` - it is being sourced, therefore allowing changes to the environment.

So you should run:

```
source /path/to/script.sh
```

Speaking of `.bashrc`, if you find the process of sourcing the script tedious, you should add this to your `.bashrc`:

```
alias aliasnamehere="source /path/to/script.sh"
```

and change the alias to the one you prefer.